# Prove that $G$ has this relationship with a $k$-partite graph.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, forbidden-subgraphs

A simple graph $G$ has $k$-cliques but not $(k+1)$-cliques. Prove that there exists a $k$-partite $H$, and a bijection $f:V(G) \to V(H)$ so that $d_G(v) \leqslant d_H\big(f(v)\big)$.

In other words, $G$ itself may not be a k-partite, but by changing some of its edges we can obtain a k-partite $H$, so that the degree of each vertex is non-decreasing.

Example: $C_5$ has $K_2$ but not $K_3$, we can change (add and delete) the edges of $C_5$ to obtain $K_{2,3}$. By doing that, no vertex have decreased degree and we get a bipartite.

Comment: Are you sure this is true?  Are there other conditions?  This is false for $k=2$, at least.  (Take the cycle graph on $5$ vertices, for example.)

Comment: Why isn't $C_5$ a counterexample, as @Batominovski says?  It has no $3$-cliques, and is not bipartite.

Comment: The claim is definitely false.  There is a triangle-free graph $T(t)$ with arbitrary chromatic number $t \geq 2$ (see, for example, [here](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2008/REUPapers/Zhang.pdf)).    I can pick $t=k+1$, and then attach a $k$-clique to this graph $T(t)$ to obtain a counterexample.  The final graph has chromatic number $k+1$, whence it is not a $k$-partite graph.

Comment: Thanks guys! Just edited the question.